# How to add code to an MVC cshtml file view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

really new to MVC and not sure how i would get my variable 'UsersFullName' from the code behind class file to the view.  With aspx and aspx.cs i would have done this:

index.aspx.cs:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

namespace TeamRequestForm.Controllers
{
    public class AddTeamController : Controller
    {
        // GET: AddTeam
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        private string usersFullName = UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName;
        public string UsersFullName { get { return usersFullName; } }
    }
}
```

index.aspx:

```
<input type="text" value="<%=UsersFullName%>" name="changeOriginator" id="changeOriginator">
```

How can I do the same in a view? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Model`:

```
public class UserModel 
{
    public string FullName { get; set; } 
    // Any other properties
}
```

And return it to your view:

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{
    var viewModel = new UserModel { FullName = // Logic for set };
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

And then in your view, declare this at the top of your view:

```
@model namespace.UserModel
```

And in the input you can reference this model by using `@model.FullName` or, even better:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, when creating var 'viewModel' the Fullname bit is erroring saying it cannot be assigned as its readonly... here is my code so far:         public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var viewModel = new UserModel { FullName = };
            return View(viewModel);
        }

        public class UserModel
        {
            public string FullName { get { return UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName; } }
            // Any other properties
        }

Comment: @ShaheenK that's because you're trying to set it, and aren't actually setting it. Because you don't have a setter you can just have `viewModel = new UserModel()`

Answer (score 1):

Viewbag is one way to do it. Adding it to your model is another. There are more options. Have a look at these articles

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/abhikumarvatsa/various-ways-to-pass-data-from-controller-to-view-in-mvc/

http://www.webdevelopmenthelp.net/2014/06/asp-net-mvc-pass-data-controller-view.html

Comment: Thanks Jonny, the first article was really good and solved my issue! :)

Comment: In that case, please approve as answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
ViewBag.UsersFullName = UsersFullName;

            return View();
        }
```

View

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.UsersFullName )
```

check out the MVC documentation on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from many ways, but these are most popular approaches:

**1) using [ViewBag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx)**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        private string usersFullName = UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName;
        ViewBag.userFullName=usersFullName;
        return View();
    }
```

and call this `ViewBag` at your `.cshtml` page

like below:

```
<span>@ViewBag.userFullName</span>
```

**2) using [ModelView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)**

For `ViewModel` approach you have to create `Properties` for your Entities in class like below:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
public string userFullName{get; set;}
}
```

and use this ViewModel into your Controller like this

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        private string usersFullName = UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName;
        UserViewModel objCls=new UserViewModel();
        objCls.userFullName=usersFullName;
        return View(objCls);
    }
```

and use on .cshtml page like below:

```
@model UserViewModel //your class refrence

<span>@Model.userFullName</span> // you will get your value here
```

Hope it will helps you. Thanks